# How to delete duplicate data including the original data in datagridview vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, duplicates

How can I delete both duplicate and original data in datagridview? I tried different codes but I only manage to delete the duplicate.

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
While i < numberOfRows

    For ii As Integer = (numberOfRows) To (i + 1) Step -1
        If dtg3.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString() = 
        dtg3.Rows(ii).Cells(0).Value.ToString() And 
        dtg3.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString() = 
        dtg3.Rows(ii).Cells(2).Value.ToString() And 
        dtg3.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString() = 
        dtg3.Rows(ii).Cells(3).Value.ToString() And 
        dtg3.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value.ToString() = 
        dtg3.Rows(ii).Cells(8).Value.ToString() Then
        dtg3.Rows.Remove(dtg3.Rows(ii))

        numberOfRows -= 1
    End If

Next
i += 1
End While
```

What I want is, to delete the duplicate and the original data from my datagridview, hope someone helps me here.

Comment: *vb.net* `!=`,`<>`,`IsNot` *C#*

Comment: First of all replace all "And" with "AndAlso"

Comment: why do you have while and for loop instead of 2 for loops, where did you define "numberOfRows"?

Comment: broo you are a life saver thank you soo much I truly appreciate your effort, i did your suggestions and it works now.

Comment: no problem man, glad i could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there you go

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each nextrow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            If row.Index <> nextrow.Index Then
                If row.Cells(0).Value = nextrow.Cells(0).Value Then
                    MsgBox("Duplicate on col 0, index = " & row.Index.ToString)
                End If
                If row.Cells(2).Value = nextrow.Cells(2).Value Then
                    MsgBox("Duplicate on col 2, index = " & row.Index.ToString)
                End If
                If row.Cells(3).Value = nextrow.Cells(3).Value Then
                    MsgBox("Duplicate on col 3, index = " & row.Index.ToString)
                End If
                If row.Cells(8).Value = nextrow.Cells(8).Value Then
                    MsgBox("Duplicate on col 8, index = " & row.Index.ToString)
                End If
            End If

        Next
    Next
```

This will also check all the column for duplicates not only the row under it like in your example, you were incrementing i and incrementing ii so you were always checking only 2 rows at the same time instead of comparing 1 row to all others..

Answer (score -1):

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dtg3.Rows
            For Each nextrow As DataGridViewRow In dtg3.Rows
                If row.Index <> nextrow.Index Then
                    If row.Cells(0).Value = nextrow.Cells(0).Value AndAlso 
row.Cells(2).Value = nextrow.Cells(2).Value AndAlso row.Cells(3).Value = 
nextrow.Cells(3).Value AndAlso row.Cells(8).Value = nextrow.Cells(8).Value Then

                        dtg3.Rows.Remove(row)
                        dtg3.Rows.Remove(nextrow)



                    End If
                End If

            Next

        Next
```

Comment: i upvoted the original post cause i downvoted you by mistake :/